# Laravel Vallet can't turn on merge_slash nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-config, laravel-valet

I have laravel Valet site that I can't get the nginx settings to accept double slash after domain name.

When I access http://127.0.0.1:8000//js/app.js the file returns 404

I tried setting `merge_slashes on` in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/valet/valet.conf` but I still get error 404.

How can I set valet to accept double slash after domain?